# recursive function in php class

Tags: php, recursion

I want to create a function in class, to create username, function will check if username exist then it will increment username like username_1. and check if this username exist or not if it exist again increment  it to username_2 till new username created. I have created this function but it return me nothing.Please help me what is wrong in my code.

```
class a{

function check_username($username){


  if($usernameexist){

    return true;
  }
  else
  {

   return false;

  }

}

function create_username($username) {

        $__name = __FUNCTION__;

        if ($this->check_username($username)) {                
            $n++;
            $username = $username . "_" . $n;
            //return $__name($username);  this return fatal error.
            return call_user_func('create_username', $username);

        } else {
            return $username;               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does this require recusrsivity?

Comment: add some debugging lines (echoes?) and see what happens

Comment: @Nanne I'd prefer var_dump(), if something... Echo is used for non-debugging purposes too, and it is a lot more easy to "turn on and off" var_dump statements using plain text replace in any decent text editor than to do the same with echo statements only for debugging purposes....

Comment: True, but I don't think that really matters in this minimal case. And seeing the amount of debugging work allready done, I don't think the OP needs to be confused with discussion about that :)

Comment: @Nanne I understand your motivation, but I'm more a fan of "do it right from the beginning" - especially with var_dump. I had too many problems coming from not using var_dump, I literally wasted days from my life not doing so. That's why I always mention it whenever the subject comes up - might save the days I lost for some people...

Answer (score 3):

No need to use recursion for this, a simple `while(){}` loop will do:

#### Plain-Jane Interator method

```
// your original function
function create_username($username){
  // check if the username (as-is) already exists
  if ($this->check_username($username)){
    // use $n to keep a counter
    $n = 1;
    // while {username}_{n} exists, keep incrementing the counter
    while ($this->check_username($username.'_'.$n)){
      $n++;

      /* If you don't want this to check to infinity, uncomment
       * the below portion. the 100 is an arbitrary number, but use
       * whatever you want as a limitation (could even make it a
       * parameter in the method). Also, returning FALSE allows you to
       * gracefully catch when max attempts are reached.
       *
       * e.g.
       *   if (($new_user = $obj->create_username('BradChristie')) !== FALSE){
       *     // user was successfully created within the max allowed attempts
       *   }
       */
      //if ($n > 100) return FALSE
    }
    // return the result
    return $username.'_'.$n;
  }
  // username was fine, return it back
  return $username;
}
```

#### Recursive method

```
// recursive username check
public function create_username($username, $n = 0)
{
  /* Same as above function, this is a check to prevent counting
   * to infinity. uncomment to apply it
   */
  //if ($n > 100) return FALSE;

  // establish the username we're testing. if $n is 0,
  // it's the original call to the function (don't add _0)
  // if it's >0, it's part of the search so include it
  $_username = $username . ($n > 0 ? '_'.$n : '');

  // check if the username exists.
  if ($this->check_username($_username))
  {
    // it exists, so make a call to this same function passing
    // the original username and the value of n + 1 (move to next
    // possibility)
    return $this->create_username($username, $n+1);
  }

  // the name, as-is, was fine. return it
  return $_username;
}
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7a357c323226b3c5b7eab3e5f23a9147f42400bc)

Comment: I have done this by modifying function

function create_username($username,$n=0) {

        $newusername = $this->add_username($username, $n);            
        if(strtolower($this->check_username($newusername)) == 'true'){
           $n++;
           return $this->create_username($username,$n);
        }
        else{
             return $newusername;
        }
    }

    function add_username($username,$n){
        if($n > 0){
          $username = $username."_".$n; 
        }
        return $username;
    }

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for recursivity in this case... A simple loop would do just perfectly:

```
function create_username($username) {

    $original_username = $username;
    $i=1;
    while(! $this->check_username($username) ) {
        $username = $original_username . '_' .$i++;
    }

    return $username;
}
```

Comment: ah, but if you do it recursively, you might be able to get a StackOverflow error and brag about it on this site. Oh wait....  ;-)

Comment: Hmm, why did nobody comment spotting my two obvious mistakes (no $ in front of variable, and no incrementing of counter?)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong in several ways and, as pointed out elsewhere, your desired function is better written iteratively.

Some of the problems with your code are as follows:

1. You are doing your recursive check when `check_username` has succeeded.  So, if you fail to find the original `$username` you are never modifying it, so never checking the modified value.
2. You are modifying the name passed to `create_username` by appending `_n` (for appropriate `n`).  Since you are passing a modified name in your recursive call you will actually end up with multiple `_n` parts on the name.
3. Since you are not limiting your recursive calls, even if this was written correctly, you would eventually get nested too deep.